# How to declare minus from same table but different column and result in different column

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

can you help me to make subtraction value such as money from same table and the result will also display in the same table. I'm really new to programming and do not know it. I use postgresql database .

my table name is `payment_with_po` and my  column name is `payment_amount` minus `total_invoice` equal to `balance`.

I want to declare when the value was insert to column payment_amount and total_invoice the result in balance will automatically displayed.
I am totally thankful if anyone can answer this, an hoping you give full answer..:'(

I am sorry I am really the beginner
the example is

```
payment_amount | 400
total_invoice  | 400
balance        |0
```

when i insert the value into payment_amount and total_invoice the answer in balance will automatically display as the answer

Comment: @hidayath pls explain what u required with an example.

Comment: @Sachu example is insert 400 to payment_amount and 400 to total_invoice.
400 minus 400 equal to balance is 0 so it will display it 0 automatically after i insert the value into payment_amount and total_invoice

Comment: u can edit your question and add the example

Comment: can u show what u have tried? r u inserting new row or updating an existing row? can u check my answer below

Comment: sorry,
example like:

SELECT payment_amount FROM payment_with_po
SUBTRACTION
SELECT total_invoice FROM payment_with_po EQUAL balance
do u understand :'( @Sachu

Answer (score 0):

I think u want to do the calculation during the insert operation in the table.

let say u r inserting `100` to `payment_amount` and `300` in `total_invoice`

then your query will be

```
insert into payment_with_po (payment_amount,total_invoice,balance)
values(100,300,300-100)
```